# Submit 2 forms and get the id of each form to update the other form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have 2 forms that are accessed in  sequence:-

1. Expiry Form
2. Setup Form

Now on the Setup form's submit button i have this formula inside the onselect property to submit the  forms:-

```
SubmitForm(ExpiryForm);
SubmitForm(SetUpForm);
```

then on the Setup Form's OnSuccess property , i define the following to set the Id of Setup Form form inside the RelatedFormID of the Expiry form and the opposite:-

```
Patch('Rebate Expiry Form',ExpiryForm.LastSubmit,{RelatedFormID:SetUpForm.LastSubmit.ID});
Patch('Rebate SetUp Form',SetUpForm.LastSubmit,{RelatedFormID:ExpiryForm.LastSubmit.ID});
```

but the RelatedFormID will always be null on both items.. any advice?

Comment: Try using: `Patch('Rebate Expiry Form',LookUp('Rebate Expiry Form', ID=ExpiryForm.LastSubmit.ID),{RelatedFormID:SetUpForm.LastSubmit.ID});`. Make sure `RelatedFormID` column is of type "Number".

Comment: @GaneshSanap i actully tried this as well,, but it did not work either.. not sure if power apps have any kind of bug in this scenario.. as the formula should work fine